# Cannot get the Tkinter to properly display

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, pycharm

Im trying to make a project for School, so I tried using a code, but when am running the code, it is supposed to display the heading as 'HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM', but it is showing an empty

the below image has the code im using.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYCuY.png)
and rather than showing the output needed, it's showing blank output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D63h2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you missing mainloop()?

Comment: You never create a root window, you never create an instance of `Hospital`, and you never start the event loop.

Comment: You should copy the code into the question instead of a link.  BTW, the code in the link should not produce any window and it should exit immediately because as other comments said it does not create any instance of `Tk` and `Hospital`, and `mainloop()` has never been executed.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is a code that make what I understand you want :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title('HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM')
    self.geometry('250x250')

    self.label = ttk.Label(self, text='HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM')
    self.label.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
```

Hope it is what you want

Comment: hi I tried, it still shows blank window

Answer (score 0):

Do that in your main function-

- create a root tkinter window `root=Tk()`
- create an instance of class and pass the object `Hospital(root)`
- call mainloop when you are ready for your application to run. `root.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

> but when am running the code, it is supposed to display the heading as
> 'HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM'

You are missing `mainloop()`

Don't use wildcard `import *`. Use `import tkinter as tk`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Hospital:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Hostipal System Management')
        self.root.geometry('400x400')

        lbltitle = tk.Label(self.root, bd=20, relief=tk.RIDGE,
                            text='Hostipal System Management',
                            fg='red', bg='white',
                            font=('times new romain', 50, 'bold'))
        lbltitle.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill='x')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Hospital(tk.Tk())
    tk.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]